# error: expected expression before ']' token|

Tags: c

It is showing  error: expected expression before ']' token|

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int  main(){
    char myname[]="rahul";
    int myage=20;
    printf("My name is %s \n",myname);
    printf("My age is %d \n",myage);
    myname[]="sid";
    myage=40;
    printf("My name is %s \n",myname);
    printf("My age is %d \n",myage);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a syntax error: `myname[]="sid";` You cannot assign any new value to an array. You can only assign new values to its elements. These are addressed using an index in the brackets: `myname[0] = 'a'`.  To copy a string, use `strcmp` and related functions.

Comment: Note that you could do `char *myame = "rahul"; ...; myname = "sid"; ...`, but be aware of the differences.

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid syntax:

```
myname[]="sid";
```

When indexing an array, a value must be given.  You're actually trying to assign to the whole array, not to one element, so get rid of the brackets.  Even with that, you can't assign to an array directly.

To copy a string into a `char` array, use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(myname, "sid");
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
char myname[]="rahul";
```

is a *declaration* - it declares `myname` as an array of `char` and *initializes* it with the string "`rahul`".  The presence of the `[]` in the declaration only indicates that `myname` has an array type; it's not trying to index into `myname`.  Since no size is specified the size is taken from the size of the initializer.  Logically, that line is equivalent to

```
char myname[6];
myname[0] = 'r';
myname[1] = 'a';
myname[2] = 'h';
myname[3] = 'u';
myname[4] = 'l';
myname[5] = 0;
```

Meanwhile, the line

```
myname[]="sid";
```

is a *statement*; you are attempting to assign `"sid"` to the result of the *expression* `myname[]`, which has several problems:

- First of all, the `=` operator is not defined for array types - you can't use it to copy the *contents* of one array to another (string literals are stored as arrays of character type).  If you're trying to write the string `"sid"` to `myname`, you will need to use the `strcpy` library function:

  ```
  strcpy( myname, "sid" );
  ```

  Secondly, in an *expression*, the `[]` isn't there to indicate array type, it's to access a specific element of the array and cannot be left empty - you must have some kind of integer expression there (which is the cause of your error message).

Note that something like

```
myname[0] = "sid";
```

won't work because the types don't match up.  `myname[0]` only refers to a single character in the array, not the array as a whole.  You can't store an entire string to a single character.   The compiler will complain that you're trying to store a `char *` to a `char`.